# Composite group join

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I want to do a group join with the following three tables using linq extension methods

Custumer
Order
OrderShippingInfo

Custumer can have many Orders and each order can have only one OrderShippingInfo.

So my goal is do a group join of these 3 tables and return a anonymous object that has one Customer and an array of {Order, OrderShippinfo}.

I know how to do a groupjoin between customer and order but I don't know how to add the OrderShippInfo in the collection

```
     Customer.GroupJoin(Order, c=>c.customerID, o=>o.CustomerID, (c,o)=> new {c,o})
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about that:

```
 Customer.GroupJoin(Order.Join(OrderShippinInfo,
                               o=>o.OrderID,
                               s=>s.OrderID,
                               (o, s) => new { Order = o, ShippingInfo = s}),
                    c=>c.customerID,
                    oi=>oi.Order.CustomerID,
                    (c,oi)=> new {c,oi})
```

Comment: Thanks awesome! Would you say this approach is acceptable or it should break up into two linq statements for clarity?

Comment: It's ok for me, but it's kind an individual thing. You have to understand what that code does, so you have to decide is it OK or should it be split.